overwrite nested object description in OpenAPI schema
In my Swagger UI, I want the description for the "Ultimate Debtor" to be displayed as: "Complete details about the ultimate debtor (the original sender of the payment)," instead of "Complete details about the person."
Problem: The overwriting of the description is not working.
Generated openapi:

As you can see, it shows "All details about the person" in the description of the PersonResponse within the PaymentResponse. I want to overwrite this for PaymentResponses within a PersonResponse.
Library:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>

Code:
@Schema(description = "All details about the payment in the core system.")
@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)
public class PaymentResponse {
    @Schema(description = "All details about the ultimate debtor (ultimate sender of the payment)", accessMode = AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
    private PersonResponse ultimateDebtor;
}

@Schema(description = "All details about the person")
@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)
public class PersonResponse {
    @Schema(description = "The first and last name of the person or the name of the firm", accessMode = AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
    private String name;
}

